# Spring boot not loading lists from two yaml files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

In spring, if we have two .yaml files as. (included in application.yaml)

```
application-one.yaml          application-two.yaml            
-------------------           ------------------- 
abc:                          abc:
 flow:                         flow:
    - id: 'remote02'            - id: 'remote04'
    - id: 'remote03'            - id: 'remote05'
```

and if properties class for this config is like-

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc")
class Abc {
    List<Flow> flow;
}

class Flow{
    String id;
}
```

then 'Flow' only from one file will be loaded i.e. flow.size() gives 2. (remote04, remote05. This depends on profiles order in application.yaml)

But if i change yamls files to -

```
application-one.yaml          application-two.yaml            
-------------------           ------------------- 
abc:                          abc:
 flow:                         flow:
    remote02:                     remote04:
       id: remote02                  id: remote04
    remote03:                     remote05:
       id: remote03                  id: remote05
```

and properties class to

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc")
class Abc {
    HashMap<String, Flow> flow;
}

class Flow{
    String id;
}
```

Now hashmap will have 4 entries. i.e. flow.size() gives 4

So does that means spring does not load List structure from two yamls and add them together?

if true, how to overcome this limitation?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I think this might have to do with the fact that "everything is a map" in yaml but not everything is a list. So the list is 1 object which has the same key in the yaml so it gets "overruled" by the first or last loaded (not sure which). However, the "map" can get merged because that is the default behavior anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because Spring boot [transforms YAML files into properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml). In the first case, the files would be transformed like this:

```
application-one.properties    application-two.properties
-------------------           ------------------- 
abc.flow[0].id=remote2        abc.flow[0].id=remote4
abc.flow[1].id=remote3        abc.flow[1].id=remote5
```

But in the second case, you get

```
application-one.properties      application-two.properties
-------------------             ------------------- 
abc.flow.remote02.id=remote02   abc.flow.remote04.id=remote04                       
abc.flow.remote03.id=remote03   abc.flow.remote05.id=remote05
```

As you can see, in the first case, you get two pairs of identical properties, while in the second case, you get four unique properties. Therefore, in the first case, two properties will vanish because they are redundant.

I am unsure whether you can avoid this. The docs linked above say that you can use `YamlMapFactoryBean` but I don't know enough about Spring to tell whether and how you can combine this with `@ConfigurationProperties`.